# Image of the button class

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]

Hello I have below code for the editor in the datatables

```
    var editorDataTableModule = (function()
    {
     return {
      editorInitializer : function()
      {
       editor = new jQ.fn.dataTable.Editor(
       {
        "ajax": items,
        "table": "#example",
        "fields": [ {
         "label": "Name",
         "name": "name"
        }, {
         "label": "Start Range",
         "name": "startRange"
        }, {
         "label": "End Range:",
         "name": "endRange"
        }, {
         "label": "Old Risk Grade:",
         "name": "oldRiskGrade"
        }, {
         "label": "Reporting Risk Grade:",
         "name": "reportingRiskGrade"
        }]
       }); 
      }
       }
    })();

    table = jQ('#example').DataTable({
     retrieve : true,
     bFilter : false,
     "bProcessing" : true,
     "data" : items,
     "columns" : [ {
      "data" : "name"
     }, {
      "data" : "startRange"
     }, {
      "data" : "endRange"
     }, {
      "data" : "oldRiskGrade"
     }, {
      "data" : "reportingRiskGrade"
     },{
      "data" : "approvalType"
     }, {
      data: "null",
      className: "center",
      render: function(data,type,row)
      {
       return '<a href="" class="editor_edit">Edit</a>/
               <a class="editor_remove" href="">Delete</a>';
      }
     }],
    });

     // Edit record
    jQ('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e)
    {
     e.preventDefault();
     editor.edit( jQ(this).closest('tr'),
     {
      title: 'Edit record',
       buttons: 'Update'
     } );
});
```

Now when I click my edit button it opens up a modal which has an update button now I want to call another function on click of update button. Since this button has no Id and is created dynamically through some inner javascript of datatables what is the best way to achieve this functionality?? Any help would be appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: Some quick guidance: look closely at the html of the modal - there will most almost certainly be a unique selector that you can compose which selects the update button.

Comment: Can you include an Id from the datatables source data and use that as the button identifier?

Comment: I have attached the image of the inspect element snippet and it shows no ID ??

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices... class, attribute.. perhaps title as I see on your code. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','button[title="Edit record"]', function() {
     // your functions
});
```

Comment: but how can you say that the title is Edit Record??

Comment: It's on your code... on the 5th last line. title: 'Edit record', I'm not sure if we are talking about the same button. Can you please share with us the modal markup to better help you?

Comment: No that is the title for the whole modal. That is not related with the button. The problem is that on click of edit i get a modal which has update button. I am using datatables and i want to call another function on click of that update button.

Comment: I understand. can you show me the markup? There must be something that make that button unique. is there any id on your modal that is a button parent? Anything? Please share your modal code with us. (go to your modal, right click -> inspect element, and copy the html that builds your modal)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your support and suggestions. I figured out the solution. In the Buttons in datatables there is a syntax like Buttons : ({})

Comment: In this label we can put a fn: function to call(); value and it calls the given function